# Accessing iFrame Parent

Tags: html, iframe

I recently got the infamous issue, of iframe accessing its parent. I tried to mimic that in a simpler htmls. So I created two files, parent.htm, child.htm. Even though they were executed locally, I am getting the usual error.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/kvaradar/Desktop/New%20folder/Parent.htm from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/kvaradar/Desktop/New%20folder/Child.htm. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Well, it was told that the parent and the children have to be in the same domain. But in my case, I am having them as local files, - Parent.htm, Child.htm.

I was assuming that they should be on the same domain. Why am I getting this error in this case? Am I missing something.

Here is the parent HTML.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<span id="myParentWindow">Some content of parent frame's span.</span>
<iframe src="Child.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Child HTML.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadChild() {
        document.getElementById('myChild').innerHTML
            = window.parent.document.getElementById('myParent').innerHtml;
    }
</script>
<body onload="loadChild()">
    <div style="border:1px solid green;height:500px; min-height:500px">

    Some content of the child frame.
    In the following span, I am trying to fill the parent's span content through javascript

    <span id="myChild"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that said error, but the `loadChild` function has 2 errors:

- It refers `myParent` instead of `myParentWindow`.
- It refers `innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML'.

The fixed script:

```
function loadChild() {
  document.getElementById('myChild').innerHTML
    = window.parent.document.getElementById('myParentWindow').innerHTML;
}
```

Even after the above fixes, I can't reprodure that error in Firefox 14. Everything works fine without any script warning or error.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for reply. I agree that the loadChild() had two errors. But with Firefox you won't usually see the errors. You need to go to the Error Console to see it. You can access it from the Tools Menu -> Web Developer -> Error Console.

Comment: Errors will always be put in the console log unless you handle it via `try...catch` block and display the error using `alert`. Fatal error would cause code to terminate unconditionally and the remaining code will never execute. Non fatal errors won't cause code termination, but it will cause a fatal one at later other part of code, which is difficult to debug. In this case, it's a gradual error. You won't notice it until the error is severe enough.